# Show cannot combine two graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

First we load the data file

```
data = ReadList["data_smp.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

I know that I should provide some sample data but in this case the structure of the list is too complicated that I cannot easily replicate them with random distributions. The complete data file can be obtained here [data](https://www.mediafire.com/?fsvv50vyzto5frz).

Then we use some criteria in order to define different colors to data

```
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := 
 Module[{s = m[[i, 6]]}, 
 Which[s == 11, Green, s == 12, Darker[Green], s == 21, Yellow, 
 s == 22, Orange, s == 31, Pink, s == 32, Lighter[Magenta], 
 s == 99, Brown, s == 1, White, s == 2, Red, s == -1, White]];
```

and then we plot them

```
data2 = Table[{PointSize[0.005], getColor[data, i], 
Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];

g1 = Graphics[data2];
```

This is the output

[image]

Then some additional coloring

```
valrange = {-2, 4};
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := 
If[(x[[5]] == 0 || x[[5]] == 1 || x[[5]] == 2), White, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];
```

and the second plot

```
g2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.005], 
Point[#[[1 ;; 2]], VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@
 data}];
```

[image]

Now if I want to combine these two plots with `Show` like

```
Show[g1, g2]
```

only the second plot (g2) is plotted. Why? Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't every point in g1 and g2 the same? So when you show them every point in g1 is underneath a point in g2.  If you Show[g2, g1] I assume you just see g1?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example, the data file is huge. By doing so, you might even find the mistake by yourself. The problem is that the upper image has no transparent regions. Please also tell us what you expect to see.

Comment: @Ymareth In g2 plot there are some white areas. These white area should be replaced by g1. g1 and g2 are two pieces of the same puzzle which fit perfectly.

Comment: So far as I can see you're plotting the same {x, y} points each time.  Once with a Table and once with a Map but in both cases, unless you're redefining data somewhere you haven't shown, your plots are simply differently colored versions of the same points.

Comment: @Ymareth Yes, I'm plotting the same (x,y) coordinates twice. But when I ask for `Show[g2, g1]` I should expect that g1 will be plotted above g2. Am I right? How can I achieve this superposition?

Comment: They're not transparent.  If there is a white point in g2 it will obscure a colored point in g1.  You could try making you color function colfunc use Directive[color, Opacity[0.5]] which will make each point in both plots semi-transparent.

Comment: @Ymareth Now I see your point. So the question changes to this. How can we change the colorfunction `colfunc[x_, cf_] := 
If[(x[[5]] == 0 || x[[5]] == 1 || x[[5]] == 2), White, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];` so that to leave uncolored the (x,y) points for which x[[5]] == 0 || x[[5]] == 1 || x[[5]] == 2?

Comment: Read up on Select and plot two slightly filtered lists of data would be my suggestion.

Comment: @Ymareth Could you explain it a lit bit more in a short answer so I could vote for it?

Comment: Little time right now, will do if I find some later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace `White` by `Transparent`:

```
data = ReadList["~/Downloads/data_smp.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := Module[{s = m[[i, 6]]}, 
   Which[s == 11, Green, s == 12, Darker[Green], s == 21, Yellow, 
    s == 22, Orange, s == 31, Pink, s == 32, Lighter[Magenta], 
    s == 99, Brown, s == 1, Transparent, s == 2, Red, s == -1, Transparent]];
data2 = Table[{PointSize[0.005], getColor[data, i], Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
g1 = Graphics[data2];
valrange = {-2, 4};
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data[[All, 3]]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[(x[[5]] == 0 || x[[5]] == 1 || x[[5]] == 2), Transparent, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]]];
g2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.005], 
    Point[#[[1 ;; 2]], VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@ data}];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative approach using `Select` following @Ymareth's suggestion

```
getColor[m_List, i_Integer] := 
Module[{s = m[[i, 6]]}, 
Which[s == 11, Green, s == 12, Darker[Green], s == 21, Yellow, 
s == 22, Orange, s == 31, Pink, s == 32, Lighter[Magenta], 
s == 99, Brown, s == 1, White, s == 2, Red, s == -1, White]];

data2 = Table[{PointSize[0.005], getColor[data, i], 
Point[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
g1 = Graphics[data2];

data3 = Select[data, #[[5]] == -1 &];
valrange = {-2, 4};
data3[[All, 3]] = Rescale[Log10[data3[[All, 3]]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := ColorData[cf][1 - x[[3]]];

g2 = Graphics[{PointSize[0.005], 
   Point[#[[1 ;; 2]], 
   VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@ data3}];
```

[image]